# Can I copy a ppd file?

Tags: cups, ppd

I installed cups and my Epson Artisan 1430 printer on a laptop running Debian Buster.  Works fine.
I did the same on a NUC running Ubuntu 18. Works fine.
I tried on a Raspberry Pi running Raspian, but when I add the printer, the Epson Artisan 1430 is discovered and I select it.  But this time the printer was not on the list of printers to select.

[image]

I tried using the ppd file from the Debian system, but now every job is "stopped".

Any tips would be appreciated.

EDIT
I tried another ppd file and got this error:
"The PPD version (5.2.13) is not compatible with Gutenprint 5.2.10."

How do I install Gutenprint 5.2.13?